# Вывод данных из console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли выводить данные из консоли браузера в элементы HTML страницы, например в `<div>` или в `<p>`?

На простейшем примере:

```js
var a = 5,
  b = 11,
  result = a + b;

console.log(result);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Тут по идее должен быть result</p>
```

Comment: Можно открыть консоль и вводить там команды. Например, `$('p').text('Ввели через консоль');` и текст в параграфе поменяется :)

Comment: Нет, мне интересно именно возможно ли синхронизировать консоль с элементами html. Это понятно что можно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно к примеру переопределить метод `console.log`:

```js
console._log = console.log;
console.log = function() {
  document.querySelector('p').innerText = arguments[0];
  console._log.apply(null, arguments);
}

var a = 5,
  b = 11,
  result = a + b;

console.log(result);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Тут по идее должен быть result</p>
```

Comment: примерно так же работает и консоль в сниппете

Comment: думаю там логика серьезней, но принцип наверное тот же

Comment: поэтому и сказал _примерно_.